# How to create a virtual path using Mongoose/Express with user name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

How to create a virtual path using Mongoose/express.js that starts with a userName(defined in auth.js controller) and then shows the file path in an express.js app?

Right now I get this, when I test the upload in localhost:3000.

```
{
  "_id": "565fb2d3d08954fa18046e1e",
  "url": "https://midden-wd-09.s3.amazonaws.com/2015-12-03/441ea6f5d25e7750940bf7c517b7d13f.jpg",
  "path": "MyFiles/Images"
}
```

But I want **`path`** to look like "You/Files/Images", where "You" is the current user's user name.

Here's my images model:

```
'use strict';

 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

 var imageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   url: {
    type: String,
    required: true
   },
   path: {
    type: String,
    required: true
    },

 });


 var Image = mongoose.model('Image', imageSchema);

 module.exports = Image;
```

This is a promise in my aws-upload.js file:

```
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    awsS3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
         reject(err);
      }
      resolve(data);
    });
   }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(user.userName);
    return Image.create({
      url: data.Location,
      path:( { _id: "MyFiles/Images", path: null } )

    });
   });
```